# mkdir with multiple subfolders not nested

Tags: python

I would like to use python to create an auto file creation. It works by following a path to 'E:\Videos/' then creating a file with the 'title' which a user inputs. I would then like to put two subfolders inside this, although it creates the '/thumbnail' file inside the '/clips' file. What would be the best way to get around this? Thanks!

I have tried repeating mkdir to create another subfolder, although run into a problem since my title is made by user input.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import time
import os

today = datetime.now()
title = input('Enter Title: ')

os.makedirs("E:\Videos/" + today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y ----- ') + title + '/clips' + '/thumbnail')

print('File Created Successfully')
time.sleep(1.5)
```

To clarify, I would like the directory structure to be as follows 'E:\Videos[title]/' and inside the [title] folder have two subfolders, one named 'clips' and one named 'thumbnail'. Hope this makes this easier to understand

Comment: I didnt quite get what you are trying to do. Explain a bit more please.

Comment: [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) will create all intermediary folders

Comment: @IainShelvington »not nested« is part of the title.  So probably this isn't what OP is looking for.

Comment: Please post the directory structure you would like to obtain

Comment: eyllanesc would you not delete my edits where i'm showing it's fixed thanks

Comment: @MeatBall It seems that you do not know the rules of SO: 1) Here we do not use FIXED, SOLVED, etc. in the titles to indicate that we have solved the problem, instead you must mark a question as correct, and if there is no answer then we invite you to post one to you and mark it as correct when you can (in 2 days) 2) use `@username` to notify me of a message

Comment: @MeatBall please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You need a [recursive method, like makedirs,](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_makedirs.htm) to make directories and nested sub-directories in one line:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os

today = datetime.now()
title = input('Enter Title: ')
dirpath = os.path.join(r"E:\Videos", today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), title, 'clips', 'thumbnail')

os.makedirs(dirpath)
```

However, if you do not want `thumbnail` to be inside the `clips` directory, you simply have to replace these last lines with:

```
maindir = os.path.join(r"E:\Videos", "{} -- {}".format(today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), title))

clipsdir = os.path.join(maindir, 'clips')
os.makedirs(clipsdir)

thumbsdir = os.path.join(maindir, 'thumbnails')
os.makedirs(thumbsdir)
```

> - Avoid using concatenation with paths, prefer dedicated methods like [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
> - Also, I personnaly like the [path.py](https://pathpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) library when it comes to handle files and dirs

Comment: »not nested« is part of the title. So probably this isn't what OP is looking for.

Comment: You have a point, I think I misunderstood the OP intention, but the question is pretty unclear to me... I'll try update my answer.

Comment: You want to avoid bare backslashes in Windows paths. Use raw strings, double the backslashes, or switch to forward slashes.

Comment: hi there! thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this does not fit my needs as it creates a folder with a date, then a subfolder of the title, then 2 more subfolders. I will try and update my question to make more sense, i'm quite new to this stuff and appreciate your reply!

Comment: Hi @MeatBall, if this solution helped you fix your issue, you're not supposed to edit your question but to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @olinox14 your answer did not entirely fix my issue, but i edited your answer to fit my needs

Comment: Are you talking about the first line? In deed, it's fixed. But you updated your question with the solution I proposed, and that's not the way this website works, you're supposed to ask a question, then eventually accept a solution if it helped you fix your problem...